# Erro ao formatar data:

Tags: java, datetime, data, simpledateformat

**Olá, estou formatando a data com o seguinte código:**

```
Date data = null;

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {

      data = format.parse(request.getParameter("txtdata"));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro ao formatar data: " +e.getMessage());

    }
    event.setEventodata(data);
```

**Ao clicar em cadastrar, no formulário abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O seguinte erro aparece:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Estou salvando isso no banco ok? O tipo do atributo é: *datetime not null*;
Há algo de errado na conversão?**

Comment: Qual o valor que `request.getParameter("txtdata")` retorna? Tenta usar um `System.out.println` pra ter certeza

Comment: O formato está errado. Altere para `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Já alterei o formato, não deu certo, porque de todo modo tenho que levar yyyy-MM-dd, visto que estou salvando no "Banco de dados".

Comment: Mas acabei de colocar um  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"--" +data); pra retornar a data e tá vindo "null", sendo que ao dar o erro retorna a data no erro, não entendi isso agora :s O request.getParameter tá correto.

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde amigo, por favor poste a sua Classe Modelo.

Segue um exemplo de formatação com SimpleDateFormat....

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date data = fmt.parse("17/12/2007 19:30:20"); 
String str = fmt.format(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pela mensagem de erro podemos ter uma pista do problema:

> Unparseable date: "2016-07-28**T**21:58:58"

Repare que entre a data (`2016-07-28`) e a hora (`21:58:58`) há uma letra `T`. Esta letra é o separador que deve ter entre a data e hora, segundo o [formato definido pela norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) (e que parece ser o formato no qual o parâmetro está sendo enviado).

O `SimpleDateFormat` deu erro porque você está usando um espaço entre a data (`yyyy-MM-dd`) e a hora (`HH:mm:ss`). Para corrigir, basta trocar o espaço pela letra `T`.

Um detalhe é que ela deve estar entre aspas simples (`'T'`), para que o `SimpleDateFormat` entenda que ela é a própria letra T (caso contrário, ele tentará interpretá-la como uma letra com significado especial, como o `y` que significa "ano", por exemplo).

Então ficaria assim:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Com isso, o `parse` será feito corretamente.